# How do I use Regex to track these URL's?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I would like to track these URL's with Regex in Google Analytics. How do I do this?

1. /productA/*variable*
2. /productA/*variable*/moreinfo
3. /productA/*variable*/moreinfo/buy

URL 3 is the endgoal and this (togehter with nr. 2) I can figure out. But I can't seem to construct a regex logic that will hit on nr. 1, but does not hit on nr. 2 and nr. 3.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Use `$` at the end the regex to match end of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these 3 different regex for each URL type:

No #1:

```
^/productA/[^/]+$
```

No #2:

```
^/productA/[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

No #3:

```
^/productA/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

This will only select option 1

```
/productA/[^/]*$
```